# Can a pod be forcefully marked as "terminating" using liveness probe or any other way

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

We have a use case in our application where we need the pod to terminate after it processes a request. The corresponding deployment will take care of spinning up a new pod to maintain the replica count.

I was exploring to use liveness probes, but they only restart the containers and not the pods. 
Is there any other way to terminate the pod, from service level or deployment level?

Comment: what's exactly your use case? it is a queue? Jobs are what you want, but depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get familiar with [Pod lifetime](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-lifetime)

> In general, Pods do not disappear until someone destroys them. This
>   might be a human or a controller. The only exception to this rule is
>   that Pods with a phase of Succeeded or Failed for more than some
>   duration (determined by `terminated-pod-gc-threshold` in the master)
>   will expire and be automatically destroyed.

In your case consider using [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/).

> Use a Job for Pods that are expected to terminate, for example, batch
>   computations. Jobs are appropriate only for Pods with `restartPolicy`
>   equal to OnFailure or Never.

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Thank you Mark. Unfortunately our use case cannot use Jobs. But thanks for the help.

Comment: Kubernetes does not provide such functionality without using Jobs. In order to think of any kind of workaround we would need more details about your use case.